# Recovering data from a very old 3.5 inch PATA Hard Disk without a PCB

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a very old 3.5 inch drive, and the PCB is not on it (must have misplaced it over the years).

Is there a way to extract the data from this drive? It is likely to have some old photos that are of sentimental value to me and my family.

**Details**

- HDD Model: SP0822N
- Size: 80 GB
- Connection Type: PATA IDE
- Speed: 7200 RPM
- Age  : Around 20 years old

Please let me know what options are available to me (if any).

Comment: The only viable option is to find another Samsung Spinpoint P80 and cannibalize its PCB. Then hope your drive will work with it.

Comment: You may be able to engage the services of a data recovery company. This is not cheap - hundreds or thousands of US dollars. How important are these photos?

Comment: Not enough to justify thousands of dollars. But enough to spend a few hundred on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try locate a donor and move the PCB over your drive. This in itself  isn't very complicated. You can check wither a site like eBay or a specialized service such as DonorDrives or HDDZone (the latter two will only send the PCB, no hard drive included).

Do NOT be tempted to move your platter assembly to the donor!

If it will work depends.

1. *Most* modern drives also require the (8 legged) ROM chip from the original PCB to be transplantetoon the donor PCB. This ROM chip contains so called 'adaptives' that are specific to each hard drive. Since you do not have the original PCB this would be a problem.
2. You need a PCB that matches the original. Since you don't have this, this is a problem since you will not be able to compare.

[image]

So, summarizing, IMO your chances of getting this drive to run and being able to access the data are close to zero.